# Could not load assembly after battery died during build

Tags: asp.net, iis, build

I've developed my asp.net application on my laptop but its battery was running low while building the application, so the laptop turned off. I now have an exception, which says:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v7.3' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
```

I'm developing a web application and I tried to load the login page.

I have no idea how can I overcome this. Does anybody know what is the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems a problem caused by a corrupted file. Have you tried to reinstall the NetAdvantage suite? (Deinstall then reinstall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the laptop died during a build that could be a broken temporary files issue.

Try **deleting the ASP.NET Temp files**, and do a Clean + Rebuild. (The ASP.NET Temp files are located at **c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files** (or Framework32, and/or v2...) and **%temp%\Temporary ASP.NET Files**

*(Note, delete only the contents of the temp folder, don't delete the folder as  you might get troubles if the IIS tries to recreate the folder, and does not have enough rights)*

Comment: After doing exactly as you specified, the problem seized to exist. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, than the problem is not with infragistics. I've updated your question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, your OS should warn before the battery goes low, so you can save your work. Try setting an upper warning level if the battery dies too fast, and you don't have a chance to shut down the computer.

Comment: And I've found another article, that mentions a few more places that could be cleaned. http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/clean-up-after-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Try using infragistics version utility to upgrade your website/solution

Comment: There is no versioning problem, this version works at every other project.