# IIS application path change leads to unexpected behavior

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an application (app1) which has shown strange behavior, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105293/infragistics-exception). I have created another application (app2) in IIS which had the same path as app1. It "worked", as it didn't throw the infragistics error, however it was unable to load some resources due to "invalid parameter", also, it was unable to load jQuery.

I've made a test because I was curious. I modified another existing application's path (app3) to the path app1. It "worked" just like app2, with the problem of not recognizing resources and not recognizing jQuery.

What is the cause of this behavior and how could I fix my applications? Is there a solution for this problem, or should I just pull my hair out?

Thank you in advance for any help,

Best regards,

Lajos Árpád.

Comment: Err... you're asking the same question twice.  I wouldn't know, had I an answer for you, whether to answer it here or there. I do know nesting applications in IIS can be a real pain in the ass due to web.config inheritance issues, and I recall similar issues when I had to deal with them, if that helps (I don't know if you're nesting or not, just throwing that out there in case you are).

Comment: This question is about changing the app path of an application and then having problems with loading the resources. The other question is about the parameter being incorrect at infragistics after having a laptop crash due to low battery power during build. I don't think they are the same, but I thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS with ASP.NET uses temporary folders to compile dlls for uncompiled code/aspx files/whatever.  IIS, strictly speaking, wouldn't be doing anything here; it's (probably) a job for the asp.net worker process(es) to invoke all necessary compilers, etc, but don't quote me on this.

When you visit the new app, unless it is completely pre-compiled, a bunch of code might need to be compiled as needed.  Very rarely, this process gets messed up.

If your website uses NuGET to get updated dlls, as at least one or more open source CMSes do, I've found, that might have to be handled as well, although as far as I know, those just get downloaded to the application's `bin` folder.   Sometimes that process can get broken if you move files around, as well.

So there's all kinds of things that could go on that might break, and the exception you getting is one of the most generic exceptions possible. It's not likely to be that helpful without the stack trace.

Going by this question
( [Could not load file or assembly App_Licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831287/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app-licenses) ), the solution to both of your problems might just be to delete your temporary files, although the solution that's voted up the most (as of 10/27/2012) is a bit extreme: you should only have to delete the temporary files for the application you are concerned with, not every temporary file for every application.  Cleaning and rebuilding your application might also work, as well as just restarting the AppPool associated with the website.

Comment: Perfect answer for this question, the problem was that temporarily the settings were messed up and without any fix it just worked after a while. At least this was what I have observed, but your theoretical insight into this type of issue was helpful for me and will probably be helpful for others, who might encounter this problem. In conclusion, of course, I vote your answer up and accept it when possible. As to the other issue: I didn't try to delete the temporary files for that project yet, but I will do that and will let you know about the result.

Comment: IIS, AppPool restart and solution clean were not helpful, so, it might be something in a temporary file. Thank you for your time.